# What do I need to do to install the latest version of Python app? TI-84 Plus CE-T Python edition

Tags: texas-instruments

When  try to open the python app on my TI-84 Plus CE-T Python edition calculator it pops this message and I don't know where to go to update the software. I do have the CE connect app on my PC but im a little bit lost...
[Picture of Calculator error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unWdG.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Mostly just a guess, but  going to that URL redirects to https://education.ti.com/en-gb/software/update/84-ce-software-update/84ce-download?q1=84-ce&count=1

Given the instructions on that site, presumably you need to download the update file, then plug your calculator into a USB port on your computer. Use the CE connect app to apply the update file to your calculator. Presumably there are some good instructions within the app, but I don't have it so I can't be sure.